# Access SQL Query to display the most recent date only for duplicate records

Tags: sql, ms-access

Below is my current MS Access SQL that displays all records.  However, If there is a duplicate account record, it should only display the record with the latest date ComputationPeriodStartingDate

Dataset example.  All non duplicates should be returned, Account 1005 is the only duplicate of which only the one dated 12/1/2021 should be included in return

| Account | ComputationPeriodStartingDate | LastName | Categories |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 12/1/2021 | Kent | Active |
| 10005 | 12/1/2021 | Nashton | Active |
| 10005 | 6/1/2021 | Nashton | Active |
| 10011 | 1/1/2022 | Steele | Active |
| 10015 | 12/1/2021 | Rich | Active |

I dont know how to get my current SQL to filter properly.

```
SELECT [TDS LOANS].Account, [TDS Escrow Projections].ComputationPeriodStartingDate, [TDS LOANS].LastName, [TDS LOANS].Categories
FROM [TDS Escrow Projections] INNER JOIN [TDS LOANS] ON [TDS Escrow Projections].LoanRecID = [TDS LOANS].RecID
WHERE ((([TDS LOANS].PrinBal)<>0))
ORDER BY [TDS LOANS].Account, [TDS Escrow Projections].ComputationPeriodStartingDate DESC;
```

Expected Result

| Account | ComputationPeriodStartingDate | LastName | Categories |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 12/1/2021 | Kent | Active |
| 10005 | 12/1/2021 | Nashton | Active |
| 10011 | 1/1/2022 | Steele | Active |
| 10015 | 12/1/2021 | Rich | Active |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using sub-query:

```
SELECT a.Account, a.ComputationPeriodStartingDate, a.LastName, a.Categories
    FROM
      (
SELECT [TDS LOANS].Account, [TDS Escrow Projections].ComputationPeriodStartingDate, [TDS LOANS].LastName, [TDS LOANS].Categories
    FROM [TDS Escrow Projections] INNER JOIN [TDS LOANS] ON [TDS Escrow Projections].LoanRecID = [TDS LOANS].RecID
    WHERE ((([TDS LOANS].PrinBal)<>0))
    ORDER BY [TDS LOANS].Account, [TDS Escrow Projections].ComputationPeriodStartingDate DESC
) 
    as a
        INNER JOIN
        (
SELECT Account, MAX(ComputationPeriodStartingDate) as max_date
        FROM
    (SELECT [TDS LOANS].Account, [TDS Escrow Projections].ComputationPeriodStartingDate, [TDS LOANS].LastName, [TDS LOANS].Categories
    FROM [TDS Escrow Projections] INNER JOIN [TDS LOANS] ON [TDS Escrow Projections].LoanRecID = [TDS LOANS].RecID
    WHERE ((([TDS LOANS].PrinBal)<>0))
    ORDER BY [TDS LOANS].Account, [TDS Escrow Projections].ComputationPeriodStartingDate DESC
)
        GROUP BY Account) as b
        ON a.Account=b.Account AND a.ComputationPeriodStartingDate = b.max_date
```

The sub-query will return max of `ComputationPeriodStartingDate` for each `Account`. Then we join it with the table on `Account` and `max_date`.

**Note:** Table name was not mentioned by you. Hence update the table name accordingly.

Comment: I did provide my query with table names.  This is the part I am having trouble comprehending in any samples I reviewed such as the one you are providing.

Comment: This would be my sub-query SELECT Max([TDS Escrow Projections].ComputationPeriodStartingDate) AS MaxOfComputationPeriodStartingDate, [TDS Escrow Projections].LoanRecID
FROM [TDS Escrow Projections]
GROUP BY [TDS Escrow Projections].LoanRecID;

Comment: I have just updated the query. I just have replaced TABLE with your entire query. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thank you so much!  It returns exactly what I need.  It will take me some time to comprehend it, but I am going to try!

Comment: I can help you with the logic of my query: Firstly, I am using your query as a table. Next, I am calculating max(ComputationPeriodStartingDate) for each Account in the sub-query. Then joining the table with the table returned by sub-query on Account and max(date). Query may look confusing since I am using your query as table.